# Update module created from local aar

Tags: android-studio, aar

Here is my setup : I have an android library that creates an aar when exported and I have an android app that uses the library as a module (it's the only way to import a local aar file).

To import the aar file as a module in my android app, I click on `File` -> `New Module...` -> `Import .JAR or .AAR Package` and I choose my exported aar file. After that I only need to add a `compile project` line in my gradle file to be able to use my library.

I update very often my library because I am currently developing it and I want to test it frequently. The problem is that I don't know how to update the module in my android app project...

What I am doing now is that I issue a `gradlew assembleRelease` in my android library project to create the new aar file, then in my android app project I delete the module in the `Module Settings` (or `Project Structure`) window, I delete the module folder at the root of my project and then I import it again. This whole operation takes around 3 minutes each time I want to test my library and I am tired of this. Do you know if there is a faster way of updating an android module created from an aar file?

Comment: I don't see how this would help, since the project does not keep a reference on the aar file that was used to create the module.

Comment: If it's copying the .aar into your project, you could just replace it with the new version, and if necessary do a clean build. I'm not sure if the build system will automatically detect the changed version of the .aar or not; if not, you'll have to do that clean.

Comment: It is extracting the aar file (and even suggest you to delete the source file), so I guess it would not detect that the source file was edited. Anyway I found a cleaner way of using a local aar file. I am posting the answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I thought that importing a aar file as a module was the only solution to include a local aar file, but it seems that it can be done easily by simulating a repository with a flat directory.

In your project gradle file in the `allprojects`.`repositories` tag, add the following :

```
flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
}
```

In your app module, make sure you have a `libs` folder with the aar file in it. Then add the `compile` line in the `dependencies` tag of your app module gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'package:name:version@aar'
}
```

Now, when you update the aar file in your libs directory, your app will use the updated version of your library.

**Note:**

- In `compile 'package:name:version@aar'`, `name` is physical file name
  of the library. For example `lib-debug` or `lib-release` etc.
- `version` and `package` can be found in `AndroidManifest.xml` inside
  .aar file. ([How to open .aar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34241411/3273962))

Comment: notice : in `compile 'package:name:version@aar'` `name` - physical file name of library *ex. lib-debug* , `version` and `package` can be found in `AndroidManifest.xml` inside `.aar` file.

Comment: hey, just to make sure I understood you. I create a `libs` folder inside my my already imported library? i.e: http://i.imgur.com/VKeOK7H.png  or do I create the `libs` folder inside my library that I use it to export ?

Comment: @Suhaib I can't recall if you have to create your libs folder in your app folder or at the same level, but definitely not in your library.

Comment: I'm not able to see documentation in the popup when hovered. Any idea?