# Extract code from .aar file Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

How do I extract code from aar file.[Accidentally my main project is on another system can't access only have aar file on my mail]

I need to extract the JNI code from aar file. I tried to change the extension to .jar but its extract .class only, Do anybody know how to extract that aar thing.

Comment: `.aar` is just a zip file, what problems can you have when extracting its content?

Answer (score 156):

*Example: libraryproject.aar*

1. Change the file extension to **".jar"** *example: libraryproject.jar*
2. Extract the jar file into a folder.
3. The folder will have **AndroidManifest**, **resources** and **library files** used in the android library project.
4. The folder will also have a `classes.jar` file, which will have all the classes in the library.
5. To open `classes.jar`, use [jd-gui tool](http://jd.benow.ca/).
6. In the jd-gui tool, `File ->Open`, `File->browse` and select `classes.jar` file.

Comment: @MaňishYadav first give a try dude. If you face any problem, lets try to find the appropriate solution. For you suspicion seriously, I don't have answers.

Comment: The OP already mentioned he can get the `.class` file out.  She wants the JNI code (the C++ code).

Comment: Step 1 can be skipped.

Answer (score 29):

In android studio, open the Project Files view.

[image]

Find the .aar file and double click, choose "arhcive" from the 'open with' list that pops up. This will open a window in android studio with all the files, including the classes, manifest, etc.

Comment: I would expect that to happen, and I think it actually happened in the past, now with AS 3.4.1 it says there's no application associated to that .aar file and prompts me to chose one to open it... I hate these things...

Comment: @FranMarzoa select "Archive" from the list.

Comment: In my case, I need to install this plugins first:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/index?xmlId=io.github.lizhangqu.intellij.plugin.android.bundle

Comment: I had to just double click on the AAR from the project view, it then would allow me to browse the source inside.  It would also allow me to compare the AAR against another AAR file.

Comment: .aar is a .jar which is a .zip so rename the file to .zip and violá

Answer (score 15):

Only two steps:

1. Rename the library file extension to ".jar", like: lib.jar
2. Extract the file in a folder with Winrar, Winzip, etc.

Answer (score 8):

.aar file has zip format, but it contains compiled code of the module only. If your .aar includes JNI, it will be in form of a shared library. You can use it as a prebuilt shared library as long as you can keep it unchanged. You cannot decompile it as easily as the .class files.

Answer (score 5):

Just open `preferences`, search for `plugins` and search `Android Bundle Support` plugin in the search bar. You need to install this plugin to open .aar and .jar files. 
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10310-android-bundle-support/

Comment: how can i open .aar file after install Android Bundle Support ?, please can you explain that's steps ?.