# is it possible to convert aar file to android studio project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, aar

Currently I have an aar file and need to edit the structure and functions in it. I need to convert it to a project in order for you to edit it. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can just interchange between .aar-file and Android Studio project.

However, you can access a lot of the project of your .aar-file as shown in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241411/extract-code-from-aar-file-android).