# local .aar file cannot be supported

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I try to add a local `.aar` file to the project as it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051137/update-module-created-from-local-aar), because I don't want to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328123/get-updates-of-aar-file) routine each time when I change my library code.

So in my project `build.gradle` file I added:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

Both my library and my app have two flavours - `alphaTest` and `myRelease`.  I want each library to be added strictly to the corresponding flavour of the app.

And in `build.gradle` of my app I have the following `dependencies` block:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '**/*.aar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    alphaTestCompile files ('libs/myLib-alphaTest-release.aar')
    myReleaseCompile files('libs/myLib-myRelease-release.aar')
}
```

Unfortunately as a result I always receive this kind of error:

```
Error:Project myApp: Only Jar-type local dependencies are supported. Cannot handle: C:\Users\...\myApp\libs\myLib-myRelease-release.aar
```

I tryed to use this format

```
alphaTestCompile  ('my.package:libs/myLib-alphaTest-release:0.1@aar')
```

and also this

```
alphaTestCompile  (name:'myLib-alphaTest-release', ext:'aar')
```

but in this case the gradle cannot event resolve the files.

How can I make `.aar` files also be compiled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use local aar dependency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869213/how-to-use-local-aar-dependency)

Answer (score 3):

Below is what I config for using `aar` file:

```
//dependencies
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') // dont change anything here
compile(name: 'yourLib', ext: 'aar') // yourLib.aar is put in libs folder

repositories {
     flatDir {
         dirs 'libs'
     }
}
```

Comment: what is an essential difference between your lines and one of my tryes?

Comment: @user2957954 it's totally different. 1. `fileTree`, 2. the compile aar lib

Comment: no! you have the same fileTree (I also have '*.aar') and you implemented one of my compile formats.